# Typeorm. Query. One to many relation

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

Everyone! Working on chat using typeorm. Here is how I organize data.

```
@Entity()
export class Chat {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @OneToMany(() => Participant, (participant) => participant.chat)
  participant: Participant[];

  @OneToMany(() => Message, (message) => message.chat)
  messages: Message[];

  @CreatedDateColumn()
  created_at: Date;
}

@Entity()
export class Participant {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => UserEntity, (user) => user.id)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'user_id' })
  user: UserEntity;

  @ManyToOne(() => Chat, (chat) => chat.participants)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'chat_id'})
  chat: Chat;
}

@Entity()
export class Message {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => Chat, (chat) => chat.messages)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'chat_id'})
  chat: Chat;

  @Column()
  text: string;

  @CreatedDateColumn()
  created_at: Date;
}
```

So I can populate data into tables like these.
The problem I encounter is
this query:

```
const chat = await this.chatRepository.findOne({
  relations: {
    participants: true,
  },
  where: {
    participants: { 
      user: In([creteMessageDto.user1, createMessageDto.user2])
    }
  }
})
```

So if user1 and user2 appear in the table participant only once this query works fine.
But when you have more than one user1 ids this query returns the wrong chat.
I need a query that will return chat which has two participants user1 and user2.

Could you help please?

Comment: I don't think querying by objects is supported, I suggest you try to filter participants by user IDs.

Comment: Sorry. I wasn't clear. creteMessageDto.user1 is actually id

Comment: I don't need participants here I need to find Chat

Comment: Right, but the `participant` (or participants, looks like a typo) field is a relation to whole Participant entity, not the ID. I think you should try something like: `participants: { id: In([creteMessageDto.user1, createMessageDto.user2]) }`. If participant ID and user ID are different, you will also have to join the table with users or filter by participant ID instead of user ID

Comment: Sorry I made couple of mistakes rewriting my code here

Comment: filtering by participant ID should work I guess, thank you

Comment: Actually, It doesn't work. I don't know the participant IDs in the endpoint I know the user IDs. 
So I  am querying participants by user IDs and then querying the chat by participants' IDs the result is the same